# How to update the AWS EC2 hostname without reboot?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, hostname

I know that to update the `hostname` of an AWS EC2 instance, I have to update `/etc/sysconfig/network` and then do a `reboot`.

But I need to do it without the reboot, is there a way to do this? I know that in some Linux distributions, you just need to `source` certain files to do this, but I cannot find what needs to be sourced in case of Amazon Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it in /etc/hosts as well. Then restart the network service with  `service network restart` or `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` assuming your network interface is named eth0

If you want to do the change for your actual session. Type `hostname yournewnane`

To check if the change was applied type `hostname` and you are supposed to get yournewname